# Firefox 4 using more battery power and slow

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I updated my Intel Atom Netbook to Natty, and besides killing the battery, the new Firefox 4 seems super slow, it takes half a minute to load a page, then the program does not respond too much at all.

Chromium is way faster, but I am uneasy using that browser, mostly because I use NoScript and am kinda paranoid.

Are there any ways to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're paranoid (I don't know why) you can use the NotScript extension for Chrome, which is the same functionality as NoScript: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn

Also have you tried removing your firefox profile folder to see if that solves the problem, located in your home folder.

Comment: I'll try it with a new profile, haven't thought of that yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to disable ipv6.

- Type *about:config* in the address bar,
  press Enter.
- Find *network.dns.disableIPv6* in the
  list.
- Right-click -> Toggle.
- Restart Firefox and try again.

There are several things you can do to speed it up. Just follow the Firefox optimization tutorials on [my web site](http://www.webgapps.org/blogs/firefox-tutorials).